# How Rails be configured to access a media resource that is not in its conventional directory location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, convention-over-configur

Let's say I have an image that does not reside in the normal location:

```
{appname}/public/images/unconventional.gif
```

But instead here:

```
{appname}/unconventional.gif
```

I understand this is a complete violation of Rails conventions, is immoral and you should never do this under any circumstances and, furthermore, why would I even suggest such a foolish thing?

Ok, now that we have that out of the way, assuming I am on Windows and therefore symbolic links are out of the question, how is it possible to set this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails does not serve these images, it lets the web server do that. You had best change the configuration of your web server to handle this scenario. If you use `Apache`, for example, it would fairly easy to set up with `mod_rewrite`.

Making Rails serve these images will be ugly, but it *is* possible if you provide a route in your `routes.rb` that matches `/public/images/unconventional.gif`, and if the file itself does not exist. For example:

```
map.connect "public/images/unconventional.gif",
  :controller => "static_image_controller",
  :action => "serve"
```

And then create a controller `StaticImageController`:

```
class StaticImageController < ApplicationController
  def serve
    image = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "unconventional.gif"))
    send_data image, :type => "image/gif", :disposition => "inline"
  end
end
```

**Warning:** if you use the above concept, note that if you use input from the URL to decide which file to serve (with `params[:file]`, for example), you need to **thoroughly** sanitize the input, because you are risking exposing your entire file system to the outside world.